# How can I create select option in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

How can I create option in my blade view ?

This is in my controller

UserController.php

```
$user = DB::table('user')->select('id','name')->whereIn('status_id',[1,2]) ->get();
```

here is the result

```
[{"id":1,"name":"jane"},{"id":2,"name":"leni"},{"id":3,"name":"marie"},{"id":4,"name":"elen"}]
```

In my view I want like this

```html
<select name="myusers">
   <option value="{{ user->id }}">{{$user->name}})</option>
   <option value="{{ user->id }}">{{$user->name}})</option>
   <option value="{{ user->id }}">{{$user->name}})</option>
   <option value="{{ user->id }}">{{$user->name}})</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [LaravelCollective](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) you can do it like this:

```
{{ Form::select('myusers', $myusers) }}
```

But you'll need to convert that json to an array, use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php) for that.

Check out this [link](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field).

Or you could do it like this:

```
<select class="text-center" style="width: 100%" name="myusers">
    @foreach($myusers as $user)
        <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: you mean {{ Form::select('myusers', json_decode($myusers)) }}